Как подключить Gradle проект как модуль к новому проекту?
У меня такая структура проекта в IntelijIdea
--TestProject
----TestLib
------CoreModule

settings.gradle.kts (:TestLib)
rootProject.name = "TestLib"
include("CoreModule")

build.gradle.kts (:TestLib)
dependencies {
    implementation(project("CoreModule")) 
}

settings.gradle.kts (TestProject)
rootProject.name = "TestProject"
include("TestLib")

Почему при gradle build я получаю

Project with path 'CoreModule' could not be found in project
':TestLib'

если изменить settings.gradle.kts (TestProject) на
rootProject.name = "TestProject"
include("TestLib")
include("TestLib:CoreModule")

то build проходит но я не понимаю почему в корневом проекте мне нужно указывать все зависимости дочернего модуля, модуль должен сам свои зависимости подтягивать по идее
Репозиторий с проектом

settings.gradle похоже что должен быть только один в корне проекта https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509839/5479247

@EugeneKrivenja но когда указываем зависимость из удаленного репозитория то мы же не указываем все ее дочерние модули и зависимости

settings.gradle не о зависимостях, а о структуре проекта.

Создавая settings.gradle(.kts) к какой-то папке вы говорите Gradle, что это папка проекта и определяете какие модули находятся в этом проекте.
rootProject.name = "TestProject"
include("TestLib")
include("TestLib:CoreModule")

Здесь нет ни слова о том кто от кого зависит, а только кто где располагается.
Далее уже в build.gradle(.kts) каждого модуля задается дерево зависимостей.
dependencies {
    implementation(project("CoreModule")) 
}


теперь понятно почему оно не может найти, но когда я хочу подключить посторонний проект полностью к своему проекту и иметь возможность изменять код и в нем какие варианты?

когда мы подключаем библиотеку через репозиторий то имеем доступ ко всему в ней только без возможности изменять код, вот мне нужно ровно такое поведение с возможностью править source код в этой библиотеке

Это уже за рамками этого вопроса, самое простое это пользоваться локальным репозиторием maven, гуглите по ключевым словам "Gradle publishLocal" и "mavenLocal()".
